# React unit tests - How to simulate checkbox checked

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

I've simple html checkbox and trying to simulate the checked event.

This one works

```
`checkbox.checked="true";`
```

This one doesn't work

```
`TestUtils.Simulate.change(checkbox,{target:{checked:true}});`
```

Incase of controlled component input text box, `textbox.value='test'` will not simulate the user behavior. Rather `TestUtils.Simulate.change(inputField,{target:{value:'sahas'}});`
 does a great job. 
Similarly, wondering whats the right approach with checkbox..